# Different rules for different views of InfoPath form?

Tags: form, view, infopath-rules, edit-form, read-only

For a list item's form: I'd like for the full view of the form to show up when a new item is created.  Then, that gets routed for approval to Approver.  I want the Approver to see a different view--let's called it Approval.  But I don't just want a different view of the same item that was created.

I want only a tiny portion of the Approval view to actually be editable.  I thought maybe I could achieve something like this by making the relevant fields read-only, but I can't seem to set things like name pickers, date pickers, etc. read-only.  I can only make the text boxes read-only.  This seems pretty limited and frustrating.  After the item has been created, the form is mostly filled out, then saved--at that point values are already there and don't need to ever be messed with again for the Approver/Approval view.

Is there a way to make other field types besides text boxes read-only?  Is there a way perhaps to have different sets of form-load-rules for different views?  What's the best way to do this?

Comment: There should be a "Calculated Value" control which is just a value that you can point to a field.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by spenvilgenius, the Calculated Value control is the solution to what I was trying to do, which was to reuse much of the original form in a different view but make most of the fields read-only because they will have already been filled out for the particular view.

[image]

Example in Designer 2013:

[image]

Example in Filler (Preview):

[image]

For showing a Calculated Value static field for a person choose the DisplayName field under the Person group:

[image]

Example in Designer:

[image]

Example in Filler:

[image]